# JSON parser for single Item in Android

Tags: android, json, listview

My requirement is simple, i have a JSON file in webserver and i have to parse it in android and i know the parsing method, but i have to display the output by different way in the following JSON file,

```
{
    "Productcategory": [
        {
            "shop_cat_id": "1",
            "shop_cat_name": "kurtis",
            "shop_scat_id1": "1",
            "shop_scat_id1name": "cotton kurtis",
            "shop_scat_id2": "2",
            "shop_scat_id2name": "Cotton Designer Kurtis",
            "shop_scat_id3": "3",
            "shop_scat_id3name": "soft Designer kurtis"
        },
        {
            "shop_cat_id": "2",
            "shop_cat_name": "Sarees",
            "shop_scat_id1": "1",
            "shop_scat_id1name": "Saree 1",
            "shop_scat_id2": "2",
            "shop_scat_id2name": "Saree 2",
            "shop_scat_id3": "3",
            "shop_scat_id3name": "Saree 3",
            "shop_scat_id4": "4",
            "shop_scat_id3name": "Saree 4"
        },
        {
            "shop_cat_id": "3",
            "shop_cat_name": "Anarkkali suits",
            "shop_scat_id1": "1",
            "shop_scat_id1name": "Readymade",
            "shop_scat_id2": "2",
            "shop_scat_id2name": "Stitched",
            "shop_scat_id3": "3",
            "shop_scat_id3name": "Unstitched"
        },
        {
            "shop_cat_id": "4",
            "shop_cat_name": "CottonLeggins",
            "shop_scat_id1": "1",
            "shop_scat_id1name": "LSize",
            "shop_scat_id2": "2",
            "shop_scat_id2name": "XLsize",
            "shop_scat_id3": "3",
            "shop_scat_id3name": "3XLsize",
            "shop_scat_id4": "4"
        },
        {
            "shop_cat_id": "5",
            "shop_cat_name": "PattialaPantsset",
        "shop_scat_id1": "1",
            "shop_scat_id1name": "LSize",
            "shop_scat_id2": "2",
            "shop_scat_id2name": "XLsize",
            "shop_scat_id3": "3",
            "shop_scat_id3name": "3XLsize",
            "shop_scat_id4": "4"
        },
        {
            "shop_cat_id": "6",
            "shop_cat_name": "Kids'AnarkkaliSuits",
        "shop_scat_id1": "1",
            "shop_scat_id1name": "LSize",
            "shop_scat_id2": "2",
            "shop_scat_id2name": "XLsize",
            "shop_scat_id3": "3",
            "shop_scat_id3name": "3XLsize",
            "shop_scat_id4": "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

I fetched the "shop_cat_name" field in a separate ListView and it looks like below,
[image: Category]

I need to display the subcategory in separate ListView for each Category Clicked.
But when i parse the "shop_scat_id1name" field, the data fetching in all the array fields with different category name like below image,

[image: output]

My required output should be like below when i click the first category and similarly for other category based on their subcategory..

Category name i click
**Kurtis**
Subcategory should be

```
Cotton kurtis
Cotton Designer Kurtis
Soft Designer Kurtis
```

By what way i have to modify the JSON structure or anything i need to do in coding part? 
Help Needed..

Comment: always you have three subcategory? if yes you can put subcategory on list and display that, and if not change your `json` structure and send your subcategory as one inner `jsonArray`

Comment: are you maintain all your categories and sub categories in Json only ?

Comment: yes, but how can i display all three in a single list view? @Shayanpourvatan

Comment: if you want show category and subcategory in one place you can use `Expandable listView` and if not just create one adapter and show that, what is the problem with that?

Comment: i already did the adapter and did showing the category names separately in one listview, when i click any category in tat list and the activity should navigate to another activity and show the subcategory of that category, for this how to do with my JSON file structure? is it possible or not? @Shayanpourvatan

Comment: yes its possible, but we must know your class struct and see your adapter. your class must have one list of subCategory and  all row in first list must have an id, then when you click on one row you need pass id of that to next activity and show right list.

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan my subcategory is not always three, it will increase or decrease based on the category.

Comment: so change your API from server, you need have one `JsonArray` in all category that have subCategory, get JsonArray and put in one List as subCategory in category class

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan so change in my JSON file by what structure i have to implement as API and answer it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47228/discussion-between-shayan-pourvatan-and-brendon)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you get the vaule from JSON like this :  String name=JSON.getString("shop_scat_id1name");
It's wrong.
Wait a minute，I'll give you some examples.

My English is very poor.Very sorry.

First
you should create a entity like this that will stored value.

```
public class Productcategory implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7249744975503046565L;

private String shop_cat_id;
private String shop_cat_name;
private String shop_scat_id1;
private String shop_scat_id1name;
private String shop_scat_id2;
private String shop_scat_id2name;
private String shop_scat_id3;
private String shop_scat_id3name;

...Ignore get and set method

}
```

Second
you can use gson or use a lot of json.getString....

```
    // this is your json,I replace it with ""
String jsondata="";
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonArray Jarray = parser.parse(jsondata).getAsJsonArray();

ArrayList<Productcategory> pc_list= new ArrayList<Productcategory>();

for (JsonElement obj : Jarray) {
    Productcategory pc = gson.fromJson(obj, Productcategory.class);
    pc_list.add(pc);
}
```

Third

Now,you get a list,you can use it for your ListView and if you want to click the item,
you should use pc_list.get(position) to get a Productcategory,so you can fill detail page.

I tried to let you know what I'm saying.But my English sucks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expandablelistview where your group will be the main category and onclick subcategory will be displayed.

To do this you need to do is create a object of product which contains shop_cat_id,shop_cat_name,... etc and then create a list of this.

Then pass this list to the BaseExpandableListAdapter, since the variable in the object maintain its position in getGroupView set the shop_cat_name to groupview and other three subcategory to getChildView.

Comment: i know to use in Expandable listview, i just need the same in listview. answer based on my question. @Vikas

Comment: well i you want to stick to listview only then you pass the list of Productcategory mention by @Mr.H and then onItemclick you get id pass it back to the same adapter via some_method(id,bool) and call notifydatasetchange.
in adapter class make private boolean member to tell what to display main category or subcategory and after doing that in getView method check what to show at which id. ie if(subcat == true) { if(list.id == id) { show sub_catagory list} } else { show catagory }
now to handle onItemClick create a getter method in adapter telling you what is clicked catg or subcatg

Answer (score 0):

you need change your json with following, as you mention in your comment that your sub Category is not fix then you must send one jsonArray as inner of all category. i write one for you:

```
"Productcategory": [
        {
            "shop_cat_id": "1",
            "shop_cat_name": "kurtis",
            "shop_scat_id1": "1",
            "SubCategory": [           

                  "cotton kurtis",
                  "Cotton Designer Kurtis",
                  "soft Designer kurtis"
            ]
    },
   ........
      // other jsonObject is same
```

you need handle id number in your code, because you have simple id number that start from 2. if have a problem with that say to me.

**Edit**

for catching value on SubCategory you must use following code:

```
JSONObject json = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
JSONArray SubCategoryArray = json.getJSONArray("SubCategory");

for (int i = 0 ; i < SubCategoryArray.length() ; i++)
   {

       map.put( i+1 , SubCategoryArray.getString(i)); 
       // with this code you have title and id of your subCategory in map
       // id start from 1 ( i + 1).

   }
```